# Как создать дерево и сохранить его в БД

Tags: c#

Использую EF Core и возникла необходимость построить иерархию категорий в виде дерева. Как это сделать?

Идея в том, что бы это выглядело примерно так

-Категория1

--Подкатегория1

---Подкатегория подкатегории1

Comment: Сделайте 2 таблицы: одна таблица категорий, вторая подкатегорий. 1 объект одновременно может быть как категорией, так и подкатегорией. Объект будет иметь список подкатегорий того же типа, что и сам объект. Для всего этого можно сделать root объект с Id = -1 являющийся только категорией

Comment: @Aarnihauta, можно одной таблицей. Добавить поле parent_id. Подкатегории будут заполнять туда id объектов категории, что уровнем выше

Comment: Под прошлым вашим вопросом я вам давал ссылку на несколько (4) реализаций деревьев в реляционных БД. Вы выбрали какой способ вам больше всего подходит? Я давал ссылки на встроенный в EF Core способ с HierarchyId. Вы ознакомились с ним?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, да, конечно, но там проблема в том, что я не могу получить полное дерево категории, ну либо я туплю) Я сейчас ещё раз изучу попробую и сюда напишу своё решение

Comment: Вы используете так называемый "список смежности" (adjacency list). Для эффективной работы с ним нужны _рекурсивные запросы_. Во-первых, не каждая СУБД имеет их поддержку в виде CTE. Во-вторых, их поддержки нет в EF.

Comment: Ох, надо бы ответ с подробным описанием всего этого сделать. Но некому меня пнуть...

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, в качестве СУБД использую PostgresSql, а так да тут получается, что я использую список смежности и получается так где Id пересекаются я и могу получить все данные, но это не всё дерево

Comment: Хотел я было большущий ответ написать, но осознал, что это неформат для stackoverflow. Нужно статью в блог писать. / Вы должны задавать _конкретные_ вопросы. Вы уже выбрали способ: список смежности. Теперь должны задавать конкретные вопросы по его использованию. А сейчас ваш вопрос слишком общий.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, я могу снова задать на СО

Comment: Гляньте эту [статью](https://habr.com/ru/post/516596/)

Answer (score 0):

А в чём возникает проблема?

Создаём базовый интерфейс`IEntity`:

```
public interface IEntity
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreatedTime { get; set; }
}
```

Реализуем этот интерфейс:

```
public abstract class BaseEntity : IEntity
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();

    public DateTime CreatedTime { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;

    public BaseEntity() { }
}
```

Создаём класс `Category`:

```
public class Category: BaseEntity
{
    public Guid NewCategoryId { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    [ForeignKey(nameof(NewCategoryId))]
    public virtual Category NewCategory { get; set; }

    public Category() : base() { }
}
```

Создаём в DataContext DbSet:

```
public class DataContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }

    public DataContext(DbContextOptions<DataContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }
}
```

UPD:

Предложение по улучшению [@Aarnihauta](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/422180/aarnihauta):

```
public class Category: BaseEntity
{
    [JsonIgnore]
    [ForeignKey(nameof(Id))]
    public virtual ICollection<Category> NewCategories { get; set; }

    public Category() : base() { }
}
```

Comment: Этот способ не универсален. Что за `Category3`? А если у меня 50 категорий которые надо удалять, редачить, добавлять новые итд итп? Делать сто классов `Category100500`? Это самое обычное дерево, единственная проблема с ним - не очень удобно хранить в бд т.к появляется много записей в таблице "Категории" если надо, и "Подкатегории"

Comment: @Aarnihauta Я и не заявлял о мега-универсальном способе, который поможет в абсолютно любой ситуации. Была задача: составить дерево из 3 категорий - она готова. Да, этот способ не идеален, но why not. Конечно, можно обойтись и вообще 1 классом, в котором будет/не будет ссылки на категорию ниже. Если есть желание, можете создать ответ с решением, которое, как вы считаете, тут подойдёт больше **\n** `Category3` - следующая подкатегория категории 2. Я ведь не просто так снизу написал "(по аналогии можете хоть 1000000000 создать)" **\n** Не всегда писать мега-универсальный код для всех случаев....

Comment: ...для всех случаев жизни - правильный подход. Обычно, такой подход занимает гораздо больше времени, которое не всегда оправдывает себя. **\n** А так, да, согласен с вами, что такое решение не будет универсальным. Решение можно представить в виде 1 таблицы Category (подробнее говорил о ней выше)

Comment: Сделайте `ICollection<Category> Childs` вместо `Category NewCategory`

Comment: `List<Guid> NewCategoriesId` явно лишнее, у дочерних элементов и так будет свое Id. Нет "уникального" для конкретного, а значит и нет PrimaryKey со всеми вытекающими. Храните `ParentId`

Comment: В который раз смотрю ваши ответы и недоумеваю: зачем всегда такое усложнение? Зачем интерфейс IEntity, зачем базовый класс BaseEntity? Неужели недостаточно простого класса Category без наследования? Ведь суть вопроса в работе с БД и EF Core.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Конкретно в данной ситуации, этот базовый класс создан, чтобы в дальнейшем не повторять одинаковый код, т.к. `Id` и `CreatedTime` существуют абсолютно у каждой сущности в БД. Интерфейс же может пригодится для репозиториев, когда автор будет писать методы взаимодействия с бд - чтобы, опять же, уменьшить количество кода. Пример: `public async Task<T> GetById<T>(Guid id) where T : class, IEntity => await Context.Set<T>().FirstAsync(x => x.Id.Equals(id));`

Comment: Допустим. Но зачем они здесь? Для ответа на вопрос (плохо сформулированный) всё это не имеет значения. PS Я бы поспорил с тем, что свойство CreatedTime необходимо всем сущностям. Более того, EF богат возможностями и позволяет создавать теневые свойства: [Configuring shadow properties](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/shadow-properties#configuring-shadow-properties)